# Visual Studio - WinForms - Add Panel On The Right

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to add another panel (with a splitter) to the right of the following image.
It currently has a Panel on the left with a splitter and 2 panels in the middle with a splitter.

How can i add a panel to the right of these, the panel must go all the way to the top and bottom of the form and be resizable with a splitter? thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you have a splitter between the blue and red-ish area?  You can place splitters within splitters.  So if you wanted to have splitters between each panel, you'd place a splitter (split top to bottom), to split between "new panel" and everything else.  Then place another top to bottom splitter on the left side (splitting between blue and red-ish).  Finally drop another splitter (left-to-right) in the right side of that (to split between dark and lighter red)

Comment: I currently have 2 splitters, one on the left of the blue panel and one between the dark and light red.
If i add another splitter and set it Dock on the right then add another panel the panel goes below the dark red panel over the light red panel.... it does not go all the way to the top of the form.

Comment: You have to use `SplitContainer`.

Comment: Use `View - Other Windows - Document Outline` to move panels in and out of other containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Change `Dock` to `None` of the main split container (I guess its name is `splitContainer1`).
2. Add a new `SplitContainer` inside your form.
3. Drag and drop entire `splitContainer1` inside the left panel of the new split container.
4. Change `Dock` of `splitContainer1` back to `Fill`.
5. Change `Dock` of `splitContainer3` (the new one) to `Fill`.

### Starting from a blank form

[image]

Comment: I must be missing something here because after following this i end up with splitContainer1 and splitContainer2.... there is no splitContainer3 ??

Also i end up with just 3 vertical panels.... are you sure you havent missed a step out?

Comment: Yes, I supposed you already had 2 `SplitContainer` in your form. I fix it.

Comment: No i started with a blank form.

Comment: Thats it, brilliant, it was that orientation property i didnt know about... thanks GibbOne